# Emgu.CV load grayscale float32 image as <Bgra, Single>

Tags: image, tiff, emgucv

I am trying to load a small TIFF image using Emgu.CV (2.4.10). The image is a 32bit (float32) single band image, but when loading it using Emgu it opens it as a `<Bgra, Single>` image.

Is Emgu misinterpreting the image or are there some method to force Emgu to load the image as a `<Gray, Single>`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to read a image from a file. If this is the case you can simply specify the image format and bit depth when declaring the Image.

```
Image<Gray,Single> myImage = new Image<Gray,Single>("myFile.tiff");
```

Comment: You're correct and I didn't specify that. I am trying to read a TIFF file and I ofcourse use the procedure you describe. The problem is that during runtime Emgu wants to load it as `<Bgra, Single>`. I guess it has something to do with the layout/format of my specific TIFF file.

Comment: Apologies, I did not realize it was causing a error. If it is only a single image you might want to try resaving it with another program. TIFF is certainly capable of handling grayscale images so it may have something to do with how the image was originally saved.